# How to use if-else in http response?

Tags: angularjs

I am just getting table datas from backend.In my table there are two fields `Approvedon` and `Approvedby`,Here when those 2 fields coming as null I need to show their values as `pending` in table.For that I have used If-else But am unable to print it.What went wrong?

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="loadLeaves()">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in leaveList">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.AppliedOn | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveType}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveFrom | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveTo | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Duration}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Status}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Approvedon | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Approvedby}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-warning noData">
        <strong>No Data Found!!</strong>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
var app=angular
        .module('App', [])
        .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.post('/leave/EmployeeLeaveList').then(function (response) {
                    $scope.leaveList = response.data;
                    if ($scope.leaveList.Approvedon == "" || $scope.leaveList.Approvedon == null) {
                        $scope.leaveList.Approvedon = "pending";
                    }
                })
            }
         })
</script>
```

Similary when the length of response is `0` then It should display `No Data Found`,otherwise it should be hided.By default In css am hiding it.
I did these and all in jquery easily,But now only am learning angular that is why lot of doubts.
Please give suggestion anyone.

Comment: what is the output you are getting? are you able to show "pending"?

Comment: isnt the leavelist an array? you are checking for the value of the property "approvedOn" on leavelist.

Comment: No am not able to show `pending`

Comment: leavelist is an object and am getting `Approvedon=null` and `Approvedby=""`

Comment: Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @user7397787 : it is possible to loop though object as well, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anoop pointed out, you just have to use ng-if for both the things that you want to achieve.

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="loadLeaves()">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in leaveList">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.AppliedOn | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveType}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveFrom | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveTo | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Duration}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Status}}</td>
                    <td ng-if="data.Approvedon!==null&&data.Approvedon!==''">{{data.Approvedon | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td ng-if="data.Approvedon===null||data.Approvedon===''">Pending</td>

                    <td>{{data.Approvedby}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!leaveList.length" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-warning noData">
        <strong>No Data Found!!</strong>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you just copied my answer and got accepted as well... wow :), OP seems to be in weekend hurry,.  :)

Comment: I didn't copy your answer. I have mentioned you in my answer as well. But you didn't take care of the 'Pending' part in the question. I have not even updated my answer after knowing that leavelist is an object but not an array.No hard feelings intended. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-if,`Like below:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="loadLeaves()">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive" ng-if="leaveList.length">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in leaveList">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.AppliedOn | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveType}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveFrom | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.LeaveTo | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Duration}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Status}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Approvedon | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Approvedby}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!leaveList.length" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-warning noData">
        <strong>No Data Found!!</strong>
    </div>
</body>
```

and remove `css` for hiding\showing(if any).

**Update:**

as per your comment *..leave list is an object and am getting Approvedon=null and Approvedby=""..`*

Since `leaveList` an object, so change your ng-repeat to: `ng-repeat="(key,value) in leaveList"`

, and for binding do it like : `{{leaveList[key]}}` or `{{value}}`